# PHP Link Directory Script

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php5

I took .zip, uncompressed it and hit my domain/

```
==> error_log <==
[Sun Sep 27 22:54:25 2009] [error] [client 24.185.130.236] PHP Warning:  require_once(../include/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/home/alexus/xxxshow.biz/PhpLD/install/index.php on line 48
[Sun Sep 27 22:54:25 2009] [error] [client 24.185.130.236] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../include/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /usr/home/alexus/xxxshow.biz/PhpLD/install/index.php on line 48

==> access_log <==
24.185.130.236 - - [27/Sep/2009:22:54:25 -0400] "GET /install/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_1; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.9"
```

so I did

```
-bash-3.2# cd PhpLD/include/
-bash-3.2# cp config.php.new config.php
-bash-3.2#
```

and now I'm gettin'

```
==> error_log <==
[Sun Sep 27 22:58:37 2009] [error] [client 24.185.130.236] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare date_add() in /usr/home/alexus/xxxshow.biz/PhpLD/include/functions.php on line 2185

==> access_log <==
24.185.130.236 - - [27/Sep/2009:22:58:37 -0400] "GET /install/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_1; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.9"
```

so the question is how do I get it to work? anyone had same issue perhaps?

Comment: what's the question you're asking, I think I missed it

Comment: We can't understand the first line of your posting. Which ".zip" and what does "hit my domain" mean?

Comment: .zip that contains that phpld script
hit my domain means i used browser and point to url that access that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date_add () was added in PHP 5.3.  Perhaps you're trying to use something which hasn't been tested on PHP 5.3.  Either install an older version of php, or check if there is a newer version of whatever you're trying to install.